# Approximate martingales by truncation

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, martingales

Let $(X,Y)$ be a $\mathbb R-$valued martingale. For any $\varepsilon>0$, is it possible to find another martingale $(X',Y')$ s.t. $X'$ and $Y'$ are supported on a compact set, and
$$
\mathbb E\big[\big|X-X'\big|\big]~\le~ \varepsilon,~~~~~~ \mathbb E\big[\big|Y-Y'\big|\big]~\le~ \varepsilon?~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(\ast)
$$

Answer (score 0):

No.  Not even for $(X, 0)$.  Say $X$ is a simple random walk on $\mathbb{Z}$.  Then if we pick another martingale with compact support, then $$\mathbb{E} [|X_n - X'|] \geq \mathbb{E}[|X_n|] - C =\Theta(\sqrt{n}).$$

Right?